# Desenvolvimento Android recuperando dados firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Olá galera venho outra vez atrás de respostas, tenho um banco em firebase que tem alguns filmes e series e até mesmo programas de tv, queria separa em géneros estes atributos, exemplo: o que for serie ficar fixado em Series e o que for filme ficar fixado em Filmes etc... mas isso eu queria colocar em cards usando o recyclerview para listar e nesse recyclerview uma separação de cada género usando na horizontal. Queria uma luz, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
public class SalaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ICRUDAction {

private MyAdapter appListCenterAdapter, appListStartAdapter;
private List<ConteudoSala> conteudoSala, conteudoSala1;


private String name;
private String a;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

//private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

```
private boolean mHorizontal;

public RecyclerView recyclerView;

public RecyclerView recyclerView2;

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DATABASE_PATH_ANIME);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sala_lista);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");
    progressDialog.show();

    getAnime();
    getFilmes();
    request_user_name();

}
public void getAnime(){
    conteudoSala = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);




    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            Log.i("onDataChange", snapshot.toString());

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ConteudoSala produto = postSnapshot.getValue(ConteudoSala.class);
                conteudoSala.add(produto);
            }

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerCenter
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(SalaActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerCenter);
            SnapHelper snapHelperCenter = new LinearSnapHelper();
            snapHelperCenter.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

            appListCenterAdapter = new MyAdapter(SalaActivity.this, conteudoSala);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(appListCenterAdapter);

            appListCenterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
public void getFilmes() {
    conteudoSala1 = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);

    DatabaseReference mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DATABASE_PATH_FILME);
    mDatabase2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.i("onDataChange", snapshot.toString());
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ConteudoSala produto1 = postSnapshot.getValue(ConteudoSala.class);
                conteudoSala1.add(produto1);
            }

           appListStartAdapter = new MyAdapter(SalaActivity.this, conteudoSala1);

            LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerStart = new LinearLayoutManager(SalaActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerStart);
            SnapHelper snapHelperStart = new StartSnapHelper();
            snapHelperStart.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView2);

            recyclerView2.setAdapter(appListStartAdapter);

            appListStartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    progressDialog.hide();
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito genérica. O que você já tentou?

Comment: poderia mostrar a sua estrutura do firebase database?

Comment: pronto galera postado minha estrutura, é igual esta na imagem, tipo... estes addFilme, addAnime, addSerie quero retornar em forma de lista horizontal um em baixo do outro sendo que cada filme, anime e serie vai ficar em seu respectivos lugares, consegui recuperar os dados mas de forma gambiarra POG e sim estou sem ideia para trazer os dados organizados.

Comment: tava escrevendo a minha resposta e ficou praticamente igual, não tinha visto que vc tinha editado kk

Comment: só precisa organizar o código.

Comment: por exemplo, renomeie recyclerview e recyclerview2 para rvAnimes...rvSeries ou recycler_animes, recycler_series para ficar menos confuso.

Comment: boa ideia, fica mais legível, mas desta maneira quando eu recupero os dados, só fica um recyclerview o restante some e não consegui fazer persistir os 2 recyclerview juntos, da tipo um bug no app e some os recyclerviews ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Crie uma referencia e lista de cada categoria. (Series,Filmes,Animes)**

```
    public ArrayList<Objeto> filmes;
    public ArrayList<Objeto> animes;
    public ArrayList<Objeto> series;
    public DatabaseReference database;
    public Query query;


public void getAnimes()
{

    animes = new ArrayList<>();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    query = database.child("projetofirebase-32c0b/addAnime");

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName)
        {
            Objeto object = dataSnapshot.getValue(Objeto.class);
            animes.add(object);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

public void getFilmes()
{

    filmes = new ArrayList<>();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    query = database.child("projetofirebase-32c0b/addFilme");

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName)
        {
            Objeto object = dataSnapshot.getValue(Objeto.class);
            filmes.add(object);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}


public void getSeries()
{

    series = new ArrayList<>();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    query = database.child("projetofirebase-32c0b/addSerie");

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName)
        {
            Objeto object = dataSnapshot.getValue(Objeto.class);
            series.add(object);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

**2. Crie uma classe para modelo de objeto**

```
    public class Objeto
{
    String nome;
    String url;
    String valor;

    public Objeto ()
    {

    }
    public Objeto(String nome,
           String url,
           String valor)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.url = url;
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

**3. Execute as funções getAnimes(), getFilmes(), getSeries()**

**4.passe as listas animes, series e filmes no seu recyclerview**